# file downloads fine over HTTP/1.1 on IOS but not over HTTP2

Tags: php, http, http-headers, apache2, http2

I have a problem were a file won't properly download over HTTP/2 on IOS, but works fine on any other OS.
The console message i'm getting on the IOS Device (connected through a macbook with Xcode) is as follows:
"Frame Load Interrupted".

When changing the Apache2 protocol back to HTTP/1.1 the files download properly again.

If it's possible to serve the files over HTTP/1.1 and most of the server over HTTP/2 would be a nice workaround.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.$document->mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    readfile($file);

    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
```

if more information is needed, please let me know

Comment: You could do that with a virtualhost configuration.

Comment: Could you explain how?